# How to check whether all values are in input DataFrame for pivot_table and create and fill by 0 some values which not exists in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, pivot-table

I have table in Python Pandas like below:

**Input:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["ID"] = [111,222,333]
df["TYPE"] = ["A", "A", "C"]
df["VAL_1"] = [1,3,0]
df["VAL_2"] = [0,0,1]
```

df:

```
ID   | TYPE  | VAL_1 | VAL_2
-----|-------|-------|-------
111  | A     |  1    | 0 
222  | A     |  3    | 0
333  | C     |  0    | 1
```

And I need to create pivot_table using code like below:

```
df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, 
                          values=['VAL_1', 'VAL_2'],
                          index=['ID'],
                          columns='TYPE', 
                          fill_value=0)
df_pivot.columns = df_pivot.columns.get_level_values(1)  + '_' + df_pivot.columns.get_level_values(0)
df_pivot = df_pivot.reset_index()
```

df_pivot (result of above code):

[image]

**Requirements:**

- Input df should have the following values in column "TYPE": A, B, C.
- However, input df is a result of some query in SQL, so sometimes there could be lack of some values (A, B, C) in column "TYPE"
- ***I need to check whether input df has all categories (A, B, C) in column "TYPE" if not in df_pivot create this category and fill by 0***

**Output:**
And I need something like below:

| ID | A_VAL_1 | C_VAL_1 | A_VAL_2 | C_VAL_2 | B_VAL_1 | B_VAL_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | **0** | **0** |
| 222 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | **0** | **0** |
| 333 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | **0** | **0** |

As you can see value "B" was not in input df in column "TYPE", so in df_pivot was created columns with "B" (B_VAL_1, B_VAL_2) filling by 0.

How can I do that in Python Pandas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html) and the `observed=False, dropna=False` parameters in [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df['TYPE'] = pd.Categorical(df['TYPE'], categories=['A', 'B', 'C'])

df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, 
                          values=['VAL_1', 'VAL_2'],
                          index=['ID'],
                          columns='TYPE', 
                          observed=False, dropna=False,
                          fill_value=0)
df_pivot.columns = df_pivot.columns.get_level_values(1).astype(str)  + '_' + df_pivot.columns.get_level_values(0)
df_pivot = df_pivot.reset_index()
```

Output:

```
    ID  A_VAL_1  B_VAL_1  C_VAL_1  A_VAL_2  B_VAL_2  C_VAL_2
0  111        1        0        0        0        0        0
1  222        3        0        0        0        0        0
2  333        0        0        0        0        0        1
```

Comment: mozawy, I tested your solutiuon and it works perfect! thank you very much, i gave you best answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the "value" columns' names as well as the missing types in the "TYPE" column, take a cartesian product of them (e.g., (B, VAL_1)) and introduce those columns with 0 initialized and underscore-joined (e.g., B_VAL_1):

```py
from itertools import product

val_cols = df.columns.difference(["ID", "TYPE"])
missings = pd.Index(["A", "B", "C"]).difference(df["TYPE"])

df_pivot[[*map("_".join, product(missings, val_cols))]] = 0
```

to get

```py
>>> df_pivot

    ID  A_VAL_1  C_VAL_1  A_VAL_2  C_VAL_2  B_VAL_1  B_VAL_2
0  111        1        0        0        0        0        0
1  222        3        0        0        0        0        0
2  333        0        0        0        1        0        0
```

Comment: Mustafa Aydin I use your code and I have error: KeyError: "None of [Index(['B_VAL_1', 'B_VAL_2'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]" - what can I do ?

Comment: what does `pd.__version__` say?

Comment: I have 1.3.2 and it seems to work. But the other answer seems better and requires little change to your code.